# "File Not Found" exception while creating sharepoint subsite collection using central admin

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010, filenotfoundexception, sitecollection

I have my own  site template, while creating new site collection using the particular template, I am getting the "File Not Found" exception, event i didnt have any information in my log file. how to resolve this issue?

Correlation ID: 10119a26-b9e0-45b8-8fda-37609838b710

Comment: Please provide more information. Search for the Correlation ID in the SP Logs. How did you create the template? Was it created on the same server? Do you use a custom master page?

Comment: Noting there in the log.Yes in same server. yes i am using custom masterpage.

Comment: check out this blog http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=744536f4%2D127e%2D4c4a%2Dbcff%2Db85408e7e7e5&ID=86&Web=70a3e89c%2Dd7de%2D44f0%2D9cd7%2Dcf99e224b81a

Comment: if this does not work, edit your web.config file and set customErrors to mode="On" to get a detailed error message and post it here

Comment: Try creating the site again and search the logs more carefully with the new correlation ID. If you are given an ID, then it's in the logs.

Comment: the problem occurs due to the feature activation bug. i have solved the error in the feature and its working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:
Go to Site settings of parent site -> under group Look and Feel, click on Master Page -> check on 3 checkboxes:
Reset all subsites to inherit this Site Master Page setting
Reset all subsites to inherit this system Master Page setting
Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL

Click OK
Check your sub site again.